# How to check if a matrix in R is full?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a pretty stupid question about matrix in R: how to check if a matrix is full in R?

For example:

```
m1 = matrix(NA, 2, 2)
m1[,1] = c("a", "b")
```

So at this time, this matrix should look like:

```
a NA
b NA
```

I tried to check if it is empty using `is.null()` and return `False`, which is what's expected here. However I wonder if there is a function in R, which can tell if every entry in matrix has an assignment (no matter what it is, integer, character, as long as it has an assignment)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The contents of the help file `?NA` might be worth reading to better understand how R interprets the NA value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is.null` test if an object is null; it doesn't look inside the matrix. Actually you can't have a null in a matrix cell since `length(NULL) == 0`; You see this error when you try to assign NULL to one cell:

```
m1[1,1] <- NULL
```

> ```
> Error in m1[1, 1] <- NULL : 
>   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> ```

---

If you want to check if there's any `NA` in your matrix, you can use `anyNA` which is the same as `any(is.na(...))` but could be faster:

> The generic function anyNA implements any(is.na(x)) in a possibly
>   faster way (especially for atomic vectors).

```
anyNA(m1)
# [1] TRUE

!anyNA(m1)          # negation tells you if it's full, here means not full
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

If the length of `m1` is equal to the number of non NA elements, it is *full*. In this case,

```
length(m1) == sum(!is.na(m1))
#[1] FALSE
```